# how to get root view of an activity from service in android?

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating an application which takes screenshots of applications opened by the user and sends them to a server at regular intervals. I am using a service for taking screenshots, but I can't find any method to get the root view of activity. Is it possible with the NDK?